# epydoc executes python file

Tags: python, epydoc

i have a python file with several classes in it and wanted to use epydoc to create a documentation from my comments. So i do on console on my Debian wheezy system:

```
epydoc --html storage_config_tool.py -o ~/
```

It always executes the python application and doc generation stops at 21%. The same behaviour when i use the epydocgui.

When I test it on a simple hello world program everything works fine. The file has > 1000 lines so i can't post it. The program itself works fine.

Has anbody any idea why does it happen? Can wrong formatting be a problem though a couldn't find any yet.

Thx 4 help

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, it's hard to say what the problem is. However, it sounds as if the code to start the application is not protected by a `if __name__ == '__main__':` statement, so the application is run when `epydoc` imports the file. Two things that might help:

1. Fix `storage_config_tool.py` so that only `class`, `def`, and assignment statements are executed when the module is imported.
2. Use `epydoc --html --parse-only storage_config_tool.py -o ~/` to generate the documentation. This skips the module import step, which may or may not be necessary for generating the complete documentation.

Comment: Yeah, thx man. Now i put the main part in if __name__ == '__main__': it works. Now it also says warnings with 7 markup errors. But i can work on this with verbose settings.